# JavaScript (jQuery?) get last div by number in id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sending comments from server to client. Now I use:

```
<div id="abc-456">
...
</div>

<div id="abc-20">
...
</div>

<div id="abc-1">
...
</div>
```

I need to parse last div number (at this example 456) and save this number (456) to JavaScript variable.
Users use "abc-20" as link: http://example.net/page/comment#abc-20
I can change div syntax (id, class,...) on server.

Can you please help me how can I modify div syntax (for easier javascript parsing) and how can I get number of last added div?

Number in id attribut not incremented by 1, but last id is always the largest number.

Comment: You could set the javascript variable on the server side. Example using PHP : `<script>var last = <?php echo $last; ?>;</script>`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would go with a class and a data element. Something like:

```
<div class='abc' data-id='1'>
```

and then:

```
var the_id_i_want = $('.abc div:first').data('id');
```

In your question you say you want the last div but 456 is the first one. So either use :first or :last depending what you want.